# Erro: Stack Smashing Detected em C

Tags: c

Eu tenho que fazer um código em que o usuário vai me dar o tamanho da matriz e os números dentro dessa matriz, sendo que o tamanho da matriz tem que ser maior ou igual a 2 e os números entre 0 a 9.

Quando eu faço o teste do tamanho da matriz, se eu usar um número maior que 2 e outro menor, dá o erro Stack Smashing Detected. O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int linha, coluna, i, j;

    printf("Quantidade de linhas: ");
    scanf("%d", &linha);
    printf("Quantidade de colunas: ");
    scanf("%d", &coluna);

    int matriz[linha][coluna];

    if (coluna >= 2 && linha >= 2)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < linha; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < coluna; j++)
            {
                printf("Números da matriz: ");
                scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);

                if (matriz[i][j] < 0 || matriz[i][j] > 9)
                {
                    printf("\nErro.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nErro.\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Aqui rodou como o esperado. https://ideone.com/qpnJks

Comment: O está todo correto e inclusivamente corri no valgrind para confirmar e toda a memoria foi desalocada corretamente. Com que valores especificamente viu esse problema ? Era no código que tem na pergunta ou numa versão anterior ?